# How do I compare two different columns on two different worksheets and highlight differences?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to compare two worksheets, and highlight the cells on ws2 if there are differences in dates in columns H on ws1 and column F on ws2. The trouble I have is that they are two different columns starting at two different cells (comparing H9+ on ws1 to F10+ on ws2) This gives me no errors but nothing seems to happen. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub matchMe()
Dim wS As Worksheet, wT As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Dim cel1 As Range, cel2 As Range

Set wS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Status Report L3")
Set wT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Demand Mapping - Active")

With wS
    Set r1 = .Range("H9", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns("R:R").Column).End(xlUp))
End With

With wT
    Set r2 = .Range("F10", .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns("G:G").Column).End(xlUp))
End With

On Error Resume Next
For Each cel1 In r1
    With Application
        Set cel2 = .Index(r2, .Match(cel1.Value, r2, 0)) 'find match in sheet2
        If Err = 0 Then
            If cel1.Offset(, 8) <> cel2.Offset(, 8) Then cel2.Interior.ColorIndex = 1  'if difference, color
        End If
        Err.Clear
    End With
Next cel1
```

End Sub

Comment: Why not use [Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) instead of `.Index`?

Answer (score 1):

I found this code online a while back, it should do what you need. Simply set shtBefore and shtAfter as your worksheet names.

```
Sub compareSheets(shtBefore As String, shtAfter As String)

Dim mycell As Range
Dim mydiffs As Integer

For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtAfter).UsedRange
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtBefore).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then

        mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

    End If
Next

MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(shtAfter).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Useful, but sadly I need something that is very targeted to specific columns, as I am comparing two separate reports with different fields, meaning a general "what's different" colors the whole sheet. But thanks!

Comment: You could try changing the range? Maybe adding `Worksheets(ShtAfter).Range(G:G)` or something to narrow the range from the entire worksheet to just the columns you need

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub comparison()
For i = 2 To 1000
For j = 2 To 1000
If Worksheets(Worksheet).Range("A" & i).Value = Worksheets(Worksheet).Range("L" & j).Value Then
Worksheets(worksheet).Range("N" & j).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 65535
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```